# Is there an effecient way to transfer a dataset in .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

My team has been tasked with moving a windows based report generator service to AWS lambda. The original code is written in a mix of C# and VB.Net code. The part of the code that runs on the windows service is responsible for the data generation and involves connecting to a SQL Server database, run a dynamic query, fetch the DataSet, convert the DataSet to a byte array and store on an S3 bucket on AWS. The client (usually a web application running on .Net Framework 4.6) fetches the file from the S3 bucket, converts the byte array to a DataSet and binds it to a custom grid.

We were able to do pretty much the same thing on the lambda except for the part where the DataSet is converted into a byte array. We noticed that there was an exception when converting the byte array to DataSet on the web application. We realized that when the web application tried to convert the byte array to a DataSet, it couldn't do it due to the difference in the type of DataSet for .Net Framework 4.6 and .Net Core.

We managed to find a way to XML serialize the DataSet on the lambda and deserialize the xml to DataSet on the web application.

While this works, I have concerns about the performance of serialization and deserialization when working with large DataSets (over 250000 records). Is there a better way to do this?

An issue the serailization also threw up is the problem with timezones. Some columsn in the dataset contain datetime fields. While we store datetime fields in PST timezone, at the time of serialization (done by lambda) it retains the time correctly but adds 00:00 to the end to indicate the time is UTC. This causes a bigger issue as the client application reduce a further 8 hours from the correct time assuming the time to be in UTC. Is there a way to let the serializer know that it shouldnt mess with the timezones?

Comment: It is impossible using `BinaryFormatter`, you should consider changing your serialization to something more universal, json maybe.

Comment: If you a comfortable with a binary format you may want to take a look at alternative binary serialization protocols. Like googles protobuf. But others have those protocols as well. Like Amazon with Ion or Facebook with Thrift.

Comment: Requesting 250000 of anything from a remote resource seems like a problem unless it's caching. However yeah as the previous comment suggests maybe you should try protobuf msgpack or just json or even grpc